# The results of my form are not being automatically emailed - why?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

First off - I am new to Google Apps.

I have created a form that I want to be automatically emailed to me upon submission.
I have set up a trigger as follows :

timeDriven  -->  Time-driven  -->  Minutes timer  -->  every minute

I have created two forms and it has collected the data.
But is is NOT being emailed to me.
Any ideas why?

-Jena

Comment: Are you using the standard Google Forms or UiApp custom form?  If it's the former, it's best to use an onSubmit trigger that way it won't run when there isn't anything new.  Also recommend, on the far right of the panel where you install the triggers, set the notifications to immediately.  If you supply code that you are using for the trigger, I can probably give you an answer.

Comment: You write a script with this `timeDriven` function or it's it a script you got on the gallery? If so, you should contact the developer.

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting problems with triggers it helps to set the notification frequency to "immediately", to ensure that errors are emailed to you as soon as they happen.